# Name Error, not sure why

Tags: python-2.7

I am going through `Python Programming for the Absolute Beginner, Third Edition` and Chapter 4 has some code which gets a user's message and prints the `len()` of the message and then tells the user if there is an 'e' in the message:

My code I typed in emulating what is in the book is:

```
# Message Analyzer
# Demonstrates the len() operator and the in operator

message = input('Please enter a message: ')
print ('The length of your message is: ', len(message))
print 'The most common letter in the English language, \'e\','
if "e" in message:
    print ('is in your message.')
else:
    print 'is not in your message'
```

When I run it and try it with any phrase or word I am getting the following error:

```
Please enter a message: enter
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/daddy/PycharmProjects/python_programming_exercises/chapter 4 - message analyzer.py", line 5, in <module>
message = input('Please enter a message: ')
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'enter' is not defined
```

I tried casting message as a `str()` by doing `str(input('Please enter a message: '))` but that gives the same error as well.

What is causing this? What do I need to do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your first line from using `input`:

```
message = input('Please enter a message: ')
```

to `raw_input`.

```
message = raw_input('Please enter a message: ')
```

`input` actually evaluates the string you pass in, so when you type `enter`, Python looks for a variable named `enter`, doesn't find it, and gives you an error.

`raw_input` just returns the string.

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked very well. I hate it when I find bugs in author's code.

Comment: Glad to help!  If feel like making this the accepted answer, I would be very happy.

Comment: I will as soon as I can, I think I have 3 minutes left before I can do so.

Comment: For what it's worth, the original code will work just fine in Python 3, where `input`'s behavior is changed to be just like `raw_input` from Python 2. Are you sure you're using the right version of Python for your book?

Comment: I am using Python 2.7.6 and the book is written for Python 3.1, so that could be the problem as well. Thanks for pointing that out though.

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped the above in a function and passed in the message as a parameter to the function. Works just fine.

```
# Message Analyzer
# Demonstrates the len() operator and the in operator


def message_analyzer(message):

    print ('The length of your message is: ', len(message))
    print 'The most common letter in the English language, \'e\','
    if "e" in message:
        print ('is in your message.')
    else:
        print 'is not in your message'

message_analyzer('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog')
```